# Getting an undefined error but can alert value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a new value into a property of an array element with this function.

```
  function updateLabel (e) {
    var labelRow = e.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var fieldPosition = labelRow + 1;
    var index = labelRow -1;
    var newLabel = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[fieldPosition].value;

    alert(newLabel);

    xyarr[xyarr.index].label = newLabel;


}
```

When I alert(newLabel); it alerts the value I want to store but when I reach the last line of the function I get the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'label' of undefined

Comment: `xyarr[xyarr.index] = { label: newLabel };`

Comment: @Paulpro that's creating an undefined object in my array.

Comment: how does your xyarr array looks like?

Comment: @CianW I don't know what you mean; there is no such thing as an undefined object.

Comment: Where is xyarr defined? Seems that it is ( or xyarr[xyarr.index]) undefined.

Comment: Could you show us the array (xyarr), and what is xyarr.index?

Comment: @ln206 should be just index instead of xyarr.index, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where `xyarr.index` is defined. Do you mean to be using `index` instead? The error message "Cannot set property 'label' of undefined" seems to indicate that the object you are trying to retrieve from your array (i.e. `xyarr[xyarr.index]`) is undefined.

You can also try using the following indexer syntax to try setting your property as well :

```
xyarr[index]['label'] = newLabel; // or xyarr[xyarr.index]['label'] = newLabel;
```

Comment: This works! Thank you, you wouldn't mind explaining how I could define xyarr.index   ?

Comment: I don't think you need to define it. It may have just been a typo on your behalf. Otherwise, you would probably want to create a class that would store an array (`xyarr`) and another property to store your `index`. However it's likely that you wouldn't need that as your current code seems sufficient.